# Installing Windows Application on Client system through ASP.NET (Example: windows update from Microsoft Site)

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET application. From that, User register, User will get email after registration. 
My Req : When user click on link provided in email. Then it should go to my ASP.Net application page . That page should install a wincows application on Client system through web ( I was inspired by Microsoft Windows update from Microsoft site)

Please provide the best approach for this

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should look at [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx) but this is for Windows based applications and if you have an ASP.Net application that will always run from a web server.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried using ClickOnce. It should only default window at client side. Is it possiblr to customise the default window. And Also What is the best way to verify security certification between Windows application and ASP.NET application.

Comment: @user517206 The link in the email should include an encrypted BASE64 encoded querystring parameter that will uniquely identify the instance of the email you generated. You can get that when your page processes and un-encrypt it at the server to extract whatever unqiue details you encode so you can check the application is valid for being installed. Something along the lines of a licence key really for an ip restricted or one time install or time limited install.

Comment: when we create Webservice in .NET (Sample.asmx). I want to use this in Windows form application .NET. Once my web server is exposed every one know my Sample.asmx and its schema,
Is there any way to prevent other to know my web service schema(WSDL) except my Windows form application.

Comment: It's hard to generalize when I don't know the specifics of your situation. Even obscuring your web service isn't going to stop someone using say Wireshark to sniff the http traffic your app generates. Ask yourself what you are trying to prevent and how serious exposing the functionality will be and gauge your preventative measures accordingly. Private key encryption will make things more secure but also decrease performance. You will need to balance the trade off of complexity and security.